# PHP/MYSQL: highscores get rank of current player with a lot of scores. (multiple per player)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For each game the user play's i save the score (and not overwrite the old score)

```
ID  Name    UserId  Score
1   tom     1       8
2   john    2       12
3   hank    3       13
4   hank    3       1
5   tom     1       5
```

ranks will be:
1 hank:13, 2 john:12, 3tom:8

Therefore to reach the top 100 of the players i do the following:

```
SELECT id, name, date, userId, MAX(score) as score 
FROM scores 
GROUP BY userId 
ORDER BY MAX(score) DESC LIMIT 100
```

The rank of these 100 people i know because of the order of the returned data.

It gets harder however when i want to get the rank of the current userId, now i use:

```
SELECT id, name, score, date, userId, FIND_IN_SET( score, (

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( score
ORDER BY score DESC ) 
FROM 
(
    SELECT MAX( score ) AS score
    FROM scores
    GROUP BY userId
    ORDER BY MAX( score ) 
) AS T

)) AS rank
FROM scores
WHERE userId =  '$_POST[userId]'
ORDER BY score DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 1
```

This all seemed to work out fine first however now i tested it with a lot of players. The players in the lower sement all seem to have a rank of 0 (rank not found)

**What i found out is that the GROUP_CONCAT function does not fully return all the results because the result is to big.** (it does not fit in its CONCAT string or something) Does anyone know a way to get the rank of a person with the same effect that works on a data set as big as i want?

Comment: How is the rank defined?

Comment: rank is defined as the one with the highest points. rank is not stored in the database

Comment: From what I gather the rank shall be which "entry" the player is in the list of all players ordered by the score.   Btw the select statement also has an error (Order by MAX(score) DESC should in be Order by score DESC) ..... the max(score) could produce unwanted troubles

Comment: so 4 players with scores 8,4,2   would be 8 1st rank 4 second rank 2 third rank (btw matthy better put that as an example so that it can be seen at one glance in the question how the rank is defined)

Comment: hi thomas that is correct, i will add an demo table in the question for reference

Comment: Your second query seems to find fine for me, giving me the correct results. Your first query can be simplified a bit though (remove the MAX() part)

Comment: pablo i think there is nothing wrong with the subquery however the GROUP_CONCAT does not work with big records

Answer (score 0):

You can do fairly simple:

```
SELECT
    score,
    FIND_IN_SET(score,
        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT score ORDER BY score DESC) FROM scores)
        ) rank
FROM
    scores
WHERE
    userId = 3
ORDER BY score DESC
```

The subquery is only executed once because it's not correlated

Comment: thx for the help Gervs however it gives the following error:  #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: Sorry was to quick, need the group concat of course. I edited my answer

Comment: If you have troubles with the record being truncated you can set group_concat_max_len to a higher value

Comment: Thx Gervs the set group_concat_max_len works however the query does not, because when 2+ people share the same score it goes bad

Comment: Let's say whe have scores 85, 85, 78 which rank should 78 have?

Comment: rank 3. the query in my question also does that although it is not the most nice query :)

Comment: Remove the distinct clause from GROUP_CONCAT. FIND_IN_SET returns the index of the first occurence for the value. So 85 will return 1 and 78 3 (in above example)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61938/discussion-between-matthy-and-gervs).